# What is the ussage of ng-typetosearch-tmp and ng-notfound-tmp?

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I was looking in the documentation of angular and ng select, but I can't find anything that mentions what these two attributes are for next to ng template.

ng-typetosearch-tmp and ng-notfound-tmp

```
<ng-select>
<ng-template ng-typetosearch-tmp>
            <div class="ng-option-disabled">
              text1...
            </div>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template ng-notfound-tmp>
            <div class="ng-option disabled">
              text2...
            </div>
          </ng-template>
</ng-select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-typetosearch-tmp` is used when `[typeahead]` is enabled to change what it displayed before the user starts typing (the default text is "Type to search"). If you just want to change the text you can also use the `[typeToSearchText]` input.

`ng-notfound-tmp` is used to change what is displayed when no items are found after a search term has ben entered. Again, if you want to just change the text you can also use the `[notFoundText]` input.

Comment: but where they came from, are a properties of ng template?